# Fatal heap corruption error in c. cant handle it and I need advice

Tags: c, debugging, error-handling, heap-memory, heap-corruption

I wrote a program that uses structures and dynamic memory allocation. I would like to get help understanding why if I press 4 (which means exit the menu) I get the error:

> HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#76) at 0x00845EE8.

It is linked to the function `deletelist()`. I really don't understand why it happens and how to fix this problem.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PRO_OP 1
#define CON_OP 2
#define PRINT_OP 3
#define EXIT_OP 4

#define STR_LEN 50
#define MAX_LIST_LENGTH 10

typedef struct reasonList
{
    char* listName;
    char* reasons[MAX_LIST_LENGTH];
    int numReasons;
} reasonList;


void initList(reasonList* list, char* name);
void addReason(reasonList* list);
void printList(reasonList list);
int menu(void);
void myFgets(char str[], int n);
void deleteList(reasonList* list);

int main(void)
{
    char dilemma[STR_LEN] = { 0 };
    int op = 0;

    reasonList proList;
    initList(&proList, "PRO");
    reasonList conList;
    initList(&conList, "CON");

    printf("What is your dilemma?\n");
    myFgets(dilemma, STR_LEN);

    while (op != EXIT_OP)
    {
        op = menu();

        switch (op)
        {
        case(PRO_OP):
            addReason(&proList);
            break;
        case(CON_OP):
            addReason(&conList);
            break;
        case(PRINT_OP):
            printf("Your dilemma:\n");
            printf("%s\n\n", dilemma);

            printList(proList);
            printList(conList);
            break;
        case(EXIT_OP):
            deleteList(&proList);
            deleteList(&conList);
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("Good luck!\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

/*
Function will initialize a reason list
input: the list to init, and its name
output: none
*/

void initList(reasonList* list, char* listName)
{
    list->listName = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
    strcpy(list->listName, listName);//equal to PRO or CON
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LIST_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        list->reasons[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * STR_LEN);
        if (list->reasons[i] == NULL)
        {
            printf("no memmory left\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        strcpy(list->reasons[i], "");
    }
    list->numReasons = 0;
}

/*
Function will add a reason to the list
input: the list to add to and its name
output: none
*/
//
void addReason(reasonList* list)
{
    char* newReason = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * STR_LEN);
    printf("Enter a reason to add to the list %s:\n", list->listName);
    myFgets(newReason, STR_LEN);

    if (list->numReasons >= MAX_LIST_LENGTH)//if no memory left
    {
        //free(newReason);
        return;
    }
    free(list->reasons[list->numReasons]);
    list->reasons[list->numReasons] = newReason;
    list->numReasons++;
    list->reasons[list->numReasons] = NULL;
}


/*
Function will print a list of reasons
input: the list
output: none
*/
void printList(reasonList list)
{
    printf("list %s\n--------\n", list.listName);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.numReasons; i++)
    {
            printf("%s", list.reasons[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

/*
Function shows menu and returns user's choice
input: none
output: user's choice
*/
int menu(void)
{
    int op = 0;
    printf("Choose option:\n");
    printf("%d - Add PRO reason\n", PRO_OP);
    printf("%d - Add CON reason\n", CON_OP);
    printf("%d - Print reasons\n", PRINT_OP);
    printf("%d - Exit\n", EXIT_OP);
    scanf("%d", &op);
    while (op < PRO_OP || op > EXIT_OP)
    {
        printf("Invalid option. Try again: ");
        scanf("%d", &op);
    }
    getchar(); // clean buffer
    return op;
}

/*
Function will delete a list
input: the list to delete
output: none
*/
void deleteList(reasonList* list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list->numReasons; i++)
    {
        free(list->reasons[i]);
        list->reasons[i] = NULL; // set pointer to NULL
    }
    free(list->listName);
    list->listName = NULL; // set pointer to NULL
}


/*
Function will perform the fgets command and also remove the newline
that might be at the end of the string - a known issue with fgets.
input: the buffer to read into, the number of chars to read
*/
void myFgets(char str[], int n)
{
    fgets(str, n, stdin);
    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the input you are using? How many characters does `list->listName = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));` allocate space for? How many does `strcpy(list->listName, listName);//equal to PRO or CON` try to store there?

Comment: Minor: `myFgets()` has `n` as "the number of chars to read", which is off-by-1. `n` is used as the _size_ of the buffer and up to `n-1` characters are read - which includes the potential `'\n'`.

Comment: are you using a debugger like `gdb`?  You should be - will make it a lot easier to diagnose the source of errors like this

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to reproduce the segfault but valgrind complained about
`initList()`: `malloc(sizeof(char))` which allocates 1 bytes (the `\0` for an empty string) while you need `strlen(listName) + 1`.

Unrelated, to eliminate the memory leak, observe that you in `initList()` allocate space for `MAX_LIST_LENGTH` `reasons` but in `deleteList()` you only free `list->numReasons`.  Suggest you just leave it to `addReasons()` to allocate space:

```
void initList(reasonList* list, char* listName) {
    list->listName = malloc(strlen(listName) + 1);
    strcpy(list->listName, listName);
    list->numReasons = 0;
}

void addReason(reasonList* list) {
    if (list->numReasons >= MAX_LIST_LENGTH)
        return;
    list->reasons[list->numReasons] = malloc(STR_LEN);
    printf("Enter a reason to add to the list %s:\n", list->listName);
    myFgets(list->reasons[list->numReasons++], STR_LEN);
}
```

If you want to be able to delete (and reuse) `reasons[i]` then in `initList()` you want to initialize `list->reasons[i] = NULL` and I suggest (for symmetry) create a `deleteReason()` function which you then use in `deleteList()`.

Another valid design (as your `reasons` are fixed size) is to allocate all the `reasons` in `initList()` (like you had). In `addReaon()` reuse the allocated string (no `malloc()` or `free()`).  In `deleteList()` free all `MAX_LIST_LENGTH` reasons.

It's a good idea to check the return value from `malloc()`.

Don't cast the `void *` from `malloc()`.

Prefer passing a variable opposed to a type to `sizeof`.  In the above instead of `sizeof(char)` use `sizeof *list->listName` or sizeof *listName`; that said` size(char)`is defined as`1` so I always leave it out.